# select spans in td that don't contain a class

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

**EDIT: I made a typo in the question, my apologies.**

```
<td><span class="price"></span></td> //selected
<td></td>          //I want this guy to be selected as well!
<td><span class="price clearance"></span></td>
```

I basically want: Select all td that don't have span.clearance. **This includes td that don't have span as well.**

I tried `$('td span:not(".clearance")');` it *doesn't* select `<td></td>`. Any clues?

Comment: Your code works fine for me, did you forget to put `<table>` and `<tr>` in the HTML? http://jsfiddle.net/5Wbye/

Comment: Same here, I had no issues. I agree with @Antony, did you forget `<table><tr>`?

Comment: @Antony this is by @Aiias: http://jsfiddle.net/rELgk/ it's wrong because `<td></td>` isn't being selected.

Comment: @meiryo It's not wrong because `<td></td>` should not be selected. `$('td span:not(.clearance)')` selects `<span>` in `<td>`, not `<td>` itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need quotes on your inner [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector.

Try this:

```
$('td span:not(.clearance)');
```

**Edit:**

Since you mentioned you also want empty `td`s returned, try this jQuery selector:

```
$('td span:not(.clearance), td:not(:has(span))');
```

Comment: @meiryo - Empty `td`s don't have the `clearance` class. Is that your question?

Comment: @meiryo - This problem is not happening for me. See my jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rELgk/. Is your jQuery version out of date? Might be a bug there.

Comment: Sorry I made a typo in my prev comment. Your fiddle is incorrect. The first two `td`s don't contain `.clearance` but only the first is selected. The `td` that contains nothing should be selected also.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me.

Please refer below code.

```
console.log($('td span:not(.clearance)'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5Wbye/1/

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: I made a typo in the question can you please modify it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td > span:not(.clearance)');   try this one.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('td span:not(".clearance")').css('border','5px solid red');
    });
</script>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td style="border:5px solid green;"><span class="price">1</span></td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><span class="price clearance">3</span></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I don't think anything is wrong with your original post besides the fact that your table is missing `<table>` and `<tr>` tags

Comment: This is just a simplified version of my code so I didn't put the other stuff in.

Comment: Could we see the rest of your code? Maybe something else is conflicting with what your trying to do.